# Concatenate object to array without merging JavaScript JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I am currently struggling with this problem. I've been through numerous forums and websites and didn't get the answer. I would like to concatenate two objets in one array without merging using this *car* object constructor,  :

```js
const car = {
  year: '',
  model: '',
  mileage: '',
  available_colors: [1, 2, 3], // numbers indicate color id
};

var garage = [];

const honda = Object.create(car);
const volvo = Object.create(car);

honda.available_colors[1] = 34;
volvo.available_colors[0] = 80;
honda.year = 1987;
volvo.year = 1990;
garage.push(honda, volvo);

console.log(garage);
```

Problem is, here is the result i have :

```
    console.log(garage[0].available_colors,garage[1].available_colors);
    -->[80,2,3] , [80,2,3]
 
    console.log(garage[0].year, garage[1].year);
    -->1987 , 1990
```

The problem doesn't appear for the other parameters, only the array. How can i have two separate available_colors arrays that belong to each object separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a shallow copy of both the `car` object and `available_colors` array

I used `Object.assign` and the `spread` operator

You can read about `Object.assign` and the `spread` operator [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-assign-javascript/) and [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-spread-operator-in-javascript)

```js
const car= {
    year:'',
    model:'',
    mileage:'',
    available_colors:[1,2,3], // numbers indicate color id
}

var garage =[];

const honda = Object.assign({}, car);
const volvo = Object.assign({}, car);

honda.available_colors = [...honda.available_colors];
honda.available_colors[1] = 34;
volvo.available_colors= [...volvo.available_colors];
volvo.available_colors[0] = 80;
honda.year = 1987;
volvo.year = 1990;
garage.push(honda, volvo);

console.log(garage);
```

Comment: I used your solution and thank you SO MUCH, i would never have found it :) !

Comment: Good catch @apsillers, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`honda.available_colors` and `volvo.available_colors` refer to the same `Array` object.

You can instead make a new array for each car, using a `slice`'d copy of `car.available_colors` as a starting point for each:

```
honda.available_colors = honda.available_colors.slice();
honda.available_colors[1]=34;
volvo.available_colors = volvo.available_colors.slice();
volvo.available_colors[0]=80;
```

This will make a new array instance for each car instance, so they don't share the same array. Note that this means future changes to the prototype value `car.available_colors` will not be visible to instances after they're created: each instance will copy the state of the prototype's `available_colors` at creation time.

Comment: Thank you apsillers for your kind reply :) !